# Using DCEF with cppbuilder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, chromium-embedded

Is it possible to use DCEF (Delphi Chromium Embedded) under C++Builder ?
How can I configure IDE ?

Comment: Let's assume it's possible, and that you've tried to install it. What problem are you having with the task?

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=7) might give you some hints.